# proxy/tunnel connections through FTP

Tags: security, ftp, tunnel

[Server A] ----- [FTP server] ---- [Server B]

Server A and B can both see the FTP server but not each other. Is there a way to create a tunnel between them through the ftp server, only using the FTP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

FTP will only transfer data to disk or from disk, so the only way to tunnel anything is to store the data on one side and retrieve them on the other side.

Comment: Yes, are you aware of such implementation?

Comment: @sivann: I doubt that there are existing public implementations, because this is a very unusual setup. And the performance for interactive applications will probably be terrible because each side has to do continuous polling to check if new data arrived.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a FTP Proxy on the FTP server, maybe your server already supports proxy connections. This allows Server A to connect to FTP Server and use it as a proxy to connect to Server B and vice versa.

Once Server A has connected to the FTP Server, the FTP Protocol allows to send the command `USER <user>@ServerB` which will result in FTP Server connecting to Server B and function as a proxy from now on.

I have some experience with FileZilla and it worked fine for me testing a FTP Proxy Product as it offers a lot of the supported mechanisms how to tell a FTP Proxy to connect to the destination server. It also displays all FTP Commands which will be send over the wire, which really helped a lot in troubleshooting.

Comment: The question is not about proxying FTP, but establishing a connection tunnel through FTP.

Comment: That is not possible with FTP. The FTP protocol does not support something which is similar to the CONNECT request in HTTp